# Почему выдаёт ошибку __init__()?

Tags: python

Всех приветствую! Попытался сделать скрипт вступателя в чаты. Использовал telethon.В один чат всё вступает без проблем, но если ввести 2 и более чата выдаёт ошибку. В чём проблема и как её решить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано, в чем проблема. А там и полшага до того, как решить.

Comment: Скрипт с помощью Telethon вступает в чаты телеграмм ! С одним чатом всё хорошо, а вот с несколькими возникают проблемы.

Comment: @Эникейщик А можно конкретнее с решением или хотя бы ссылку на статью. Я не дурак и интернетом пользоваться умею. Если бы это можно было найти в интернете, я бы не писал сюда.

Comment: @andreymal Как её решать?

Comment: Не пытаться запихивать аргументов в класс больше, чем он способен принять.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class test():
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        
>>> test(1,2)
<__main__.test object at 0x0000000002DB4730>
>>> class test():
    def __init__(x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        
>>> test(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    test(1,2)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
>>>
```

P.S. Перед созданием ботов неплохо бы узнать синтаксис самого Python.